# Print.JS - set default print settings

Tags: javascript, web, printing

I am trying to implement a print PDF option in an application.  I found print.js and looks like this may help.  However, I want to set default print options to make sure it prints to the correct scale (i.e.. 100%).
Can print.js do this? If not, does anyone have a suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this can be achieved straight forward or not. However there is a workaround for which you need to follow these steps:

1. Convert your pdf files in **base64 format**
2. Convert your **base64 pdf** to **base64 png** using **pdf.js**
3. Render **base64 pngs** as **html in img tag** where you application related styles like margin, scales, etc. can be applied
4. Print your html content with **print.js**

You can check this article solving similar type of problem
https://medium.com/@vicky.sharma8127344/print-single-or-multiple-files-with-print-js-and-pdf-js-ab9c8347a309